# Sort a multi-dimensional array on two subarray values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I would like to sort an array on `eta` ASC then `ab` ASC.

Here's the input array:

```
$res_ubr=array(
    "0"=>array(
        "ab"=>"jdfd",
        "bb"=>"iweuiru",
        "eta"=>4
    ),
    "1"=>array(
        "ab"=>"dsdjdfd",
        "bb"=>"iuiru",
        "eta"=>5
    ),
    "2"=>array(
        "ab"=>"jdgfd",
        "bb"=>"edfguiru",
        "eta"=>2
    ),
    "3"=>array(
        "ab"=>"err",
        "bb"=>"iuierru",
        "eta"=>2
    ),
    "4"=>array(
        "ab"=>"fdfdf",
        "bb"=>"dfdf",
        "eta"=>3
    )
);
```

Here is my expected result:

```
[
  ['ab'=>'err', 'bb'=>'iuierru', 'eta'=>2],
  ['ab'=>'jdgfd', 'bb'=>'edfguiru', 'eta'=>2],
  ['ab'=>'fdfdf', 'bb'=>'dfdf', 'eta'=>3],
  ['ab'=>'jdfd', 'bb'=>'iweuiru', 'eta'=>4],
  ['ab'=>'dsdjdfd', 'bb'=>'iuiru', 'eta'=>5]
]
```

This is what I've tried:

```
$res2=$res_ubr;
$temp=array();  
foreach($res_ubr as $key=>$val){
    foreach($res2 as $k=>$v){
        if($val['eta']>$v['eta']){
            $temp[]=$res_ubr[$key];                 
            $res_ubr[$key] =$res_ubr[$k];                   
            $res_ubr[$k]=$temp[];                               
        }
    }                         
}
print_r($res_ubr);
```

For context, the eta value is the time in minutes that the cab is expected to arrive.

Comment: `usort($res_ubr, function($a, $b) { return $a['eta'] <=> $b['eta']; });`

Comment: @MarkBaker please do not post answers as comments.  This can lead to incorrect answers (I'm not saying yours is) that cannot be downvoted, answers that have no explanation, questions that are abandoned by the OP, SO readers that are confused about where the best answer on the page is.  I think the spaceship operator has a minimum PHP version -- that would be important to include in your posted answer.

Comment: @MarkBaker code not working . n no excel it's an associative array depending on one of its key and value the entire array must be sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to assign a unique temporary key.  There are two eta's with a value of `2` in your input array, so you will need to provide a "tie breaker".  I am using the `ab` value to dictate the sorting order when two duplicate `eta`s exist.  I'm arbitrarily padding the `eta` values to an 8 digit number to ensure that numeric sorting occurs as intended.  Without left padding with zeros, `10` would come before `2` because the temporary keys will be sorted as strings (one character at a time from left to right) and `1` comes before `2`.

```
foreach($res_ubr as $sub){
    $result[str_pad($sub["eta"],8,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).$sub["ab"]]=$sub;
}
ksort($result);
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Because you say the eta are taxi arrival times, I'd bet your business that no eta is going to be in the tens of millions of minutes, so you can reduce the padding amount from `8` down to what ever is reasonably expected.

Keep in mind that if there is ever a duplicate temporary key (a matching pair of eta & ab), then my method will overwrite the first element with the second and you will have missing data.  If this is a remote possibility, you should also append `bb` to the temporary key.  If this, again, at risk of being a duplicate, you should add a randomly generated string of numbers to prevent your data being erased.

Output with eta ASC, ab ASC:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ab' => 'err',
    'bb' => 'iuierru',
    'eta' => 2,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'ab' => 'jdgfd',
    'bb' => 'edfguiru',
    'eta' => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'ab' => 'fdfdf',
    'bb' => 'dfdf',
    'eta' => 3,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'ab' => 'jdfd',
    'bb' => 'iweuiru',
    'eta' => 4,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'ab' => 'dsdjdfd',
    'bb' => 'iuiru',
    'eta' => 5,
  ),
)
```

Comment: eta can be duplicate values  as the other values are varying an d the code doesnt work

Comment: @hir it works for me: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/af944a39abb33b0d0e288798051f2de5b4cef4ab

Comment: @hir how high do your eta values get?  I may have to pad the keys with leading zeros.

Comment: its the time in minutes which informs u about the cab arriving in minutes

Comment: @hir can you give me some more clarity on how/why this isn't working for you?  I don't know what needs to be fixed.  Your question doesn't show a properly sorted expected output.  What is wrong with my output?

Comment: @hir Your question just became more confusing after your last edit.  Your input looks properly sorted on eta, but your output has no order at all.  What do you REALLY want?  What is the secondary sorting factor when two eta are the same?  Your first $res_ubr array seems sorted on eta ASC then bb ASC -- is this what you want?

Comment: works:). but i understand can u explain $result[str_pad($sub["eta"],8,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).$sub["ab"]]

Comment: You can see my temporary keys here:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/65a6ea75f3a172830badac0980f6ae833c553c65  I'll update my answer with some explanation.